# What's the state of Kaspersky (on Android) in 2024?

Tags: security, malware, antivirus

TL;DR, is Kaspersky safe to use given the current political situation?

I decided to download an antivirus and scan my device after accidentally clicking on a really suspicious link. Once I was done using Kaspersky, I remembered the recommendations not to use Kasperski due to potential ties with the Russian government. Not to make it too political, I quickly uninstalled the app right after the scan, and there wasn't anything sucpisious on my phone. Plus, I wasn't using any other apps during the scan, so there's no chance it could've keylogged anything. However, it did ask for access to my files, which I granted.

I downloaded the app from the Play Store on a non-rooted phone, so I guess that's some reassurance. There are authenticator apps and other important stuff on my phone, which is kind of worrying me now. I see lots of people still using Kaspersky, but I wonder if anyone's really dug deep to ensure everything's nice and clean. I'm curious about how far a shady app from the Play Store could go in terms of messing with other apps' data or sending files somewhere. Just to note, I'm not worried about my usage data, I'm worried about credentials and tampering with authenticators. And normally, I wouldn't worry about any other app, but when it's created by cybersecurity experts possibly backed by a government, that feels different to me.